# Random angle in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, angle

I'm trying to write a matlab program which is able to a random walk, but each step/vector has the same length and the thing that determines the direction is a "random" angle. The angle is not quite random since it has some specific boundary conditions. I'm fairly new to matlab, so if anybody have tips or links to webpages feel free to post them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function `rand(1)` to generate an observation of a uniform random variable drawn from the range `[0,1]`.  You can then convert this variable into the range of your angles.  The code below might do the trick.

```
randVal = rand(1); % Generate observation of random variable
randAngle = randVal*(maxAngle-minAngle) + minAngle; % Map observation to angle
```